# Error in while (tol > 1e-05) { : missing value in code Newton method in R

Tags: r, newtons-method

I am trying Newton method for finding the minimum of
f(x) = 7x-log(x)

x_0 =0.01

this is my code:

```
x<-0.01
tol<-10
count<-0
while(tol>1e-5){
  count<-count+1
  fx<-7*x-log(x)
  fprimex<-7-(1/x)
  xnew<-x-fx/fprimex
  tol<-abs(xnew-x)
  x<-xnew
}
x
tol
count
```

but there is erorr
**((Error in while (tol > 1e-05) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In log(x) : NaNs produced))**

HOW CAN I FIX MY CODE.

Comment: It is the same. I got the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As x approaches the minimum, the slope approaches 0 and the next estimate making x<0 and thus a NaN for `log(x)`.

Your loop above is solving `f(x)=0` which does not have a real root, thus the failure noted above. To find the minimum or maximum, find where the slope of the derivative is equal to 0.  Solve `fprime(x)` = 0, in this case the minimum is at 1/7.